# Replicating Bootstraps main nav and subnav

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I need to quickly knock up the functionality of the twitter bootstraps main navigation and sub navigation e.g. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html (when you scroll the subnav becomes fixed to that main navigation)

Has anyone implemented this or are there any tutorials?

Comment: The functionality you see there is not included in the Bootstrap framework. They're using jQuery to determine the position and then to add or remove the "subnav-fixed" class. You can get a feel of how they're doing it by checking out http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js and searching for "subnav"

Comment: FYI, this feature should be implemented in [v2.1.0](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1189)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Here is my code to implement this feature:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    // If has not activated (has no attribute "data-top"
    if (!$('.subnav').attr('data-top')) {
        // If already fixed, then do nothing
        if ($('.subnav').hasClass('subnav-fixed')) return;
        // Remember top position
        var offset = $('.subnav').offset()
        $('.subnav').attr('data-top', offset.top);
    }

    if ($('.subnav').attr('data-top') - $('.subnav').outerHeight() <= $(this).scrollTop())
        $('.subnav').addClass('subnav-fixed');
    else
        $('.subnav').removeClass('subnav-fixed');
});
```

Comment: This has a side effect of affecting all absolutely positioned items on the page. Is there an easy way around it?

Comment: Is there a way to integrate scrollspy with this as seen on the Twitter Bootstrap component page?

Comment: This works great, I'm just trying to understand it as I have a need to implement this in a module, without having a dependency on jQuery - What's the purpose of `$('.subnav').outerHeight()`?  Is that to allow for an additional main nav?  I assume `offset.top` will already be the top of the element?

Comment: It's not the top of the element. This is height of the element including padding and border: http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Comment: I had to replace `if ($('.subnav').attr('data-top') - $('.subnav').outerHeight() <= ...` with `if ($('.subnav').attr('data-top') + $('.subnav').outerHeight() <= ...` to avoid glitches when the page wasn't high enough

Answer (score 24):

As of 2012-12-04 the accepted answer is no longer the best choise, since the desired functionality has been included into Bootstrap.
Please see [Affix JavaScript component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) which is part of Bootstrap JS

Comment: Just searching it :) 
Dear stackoverflow freands it's really most correct and easy way for today don't try previous tricks.

Comment: Initially I agreed, but I suppose if you aren't using Bootstrap, there's no point including it just for this feature. Unless I am missing something, both solutions seem to function the same.

Comment: @SethMW This question is tagged with twitter-bootstrap tag, which implies that it is Bootstrap-related thing. Indeed, the accepted answer is nice bootstrap-free solution, but for those using Bootstrap  I believe it's better to use what Bootstrap offers.

Answer (score 12):

Great Answer from @Oleg,

For people like me who want to reproduce the responsive behaviour of the .subnav

Here is the css code (without colors, borders and effects)

```
body {  padding-top: 90px; }
@media (max-width: 980px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
.subnav {
    width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .subnav {
        position: static;
        top: auto;
        z-index: auto;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
    .subnav .nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .subnav-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
  }
 .subnav-fixed .nav {
    width: 938px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1210px) {
  .subnav-fixed .nav {
    width: 1168px;
  }
}
```

If you want to clone the style of the menu (including colors, borders and effects)

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/ydY6W/

Answer (score 0):

The two answers above work great, but I just thought I'd let people know that I've made this into a module (without the jQuery dependency) available at [ForbesLindesay/booting-sub-nav](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/booting-sub-nav).  It can be used standalone with a script tag or via https://github.com/component/component/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another code

```
$(function(){
  var
    $win = $(window),
    $filter = $('.navbar'),
    $filterSpacer = $('<div />', {
      "class": "filter-drop-spacer",
      "height": $filter.outerHeight()
    });
  $win.scroll(function(){     
    if(!$filter.hasClass('navbar-fixed-top')){
        if($win.scrollTop() > $filter.offset().top){
        $filter.before($filterSpacer);
        $filter.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
      }
    }else if ($filter.hasClass('navbar-fixed-top')){
      if($win.scrollTop() < $filterSpacer.offset().top){
      $filter.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
      $filterSpacer.remove();
    }
    } 
  });
});
```