# jquery code does not work fine with differents urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have this jquery code:

```
$(function(){

    var $win = $(window);
    var $nav = $('.subnav');
    var navTop = $('.subnav').length && $('.subnav').offset().top - 38;
    var isFixed = 0;

    processScroll();

    $win.on('scroll', processScroll);

    function processScroll() {
        console.log('test');
        var i, scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop >= navTop && !isFixed) {
            isFixed = 1;
            $nav.addClass('subnav-fixed');
        } else if (scrollTop <= navTop && isFixed) {
            isFixed = 0;
            $nav.removeClass('subnav-fixed');
        }
    };
})
```

If I have this url for example:

`http://mydomain.com/posts` or `http://mydomain.com` or `http://mydomain.com/post?utf8=✓&search=`

the code does works fine, but if I have for example:

`http://mydomain.com/post?utf8=✓&search=port` or `http://mydomain.com/post?utf8=✓&search=word`

The code does not works fine...

**Why if I pass a param for url with my search engine the code does not works fine?**

Thank you very much!

### Edited

I am using this sunspot solr for my as search engine

http://sunspot.github.com/

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the `search` variable is handled? Maybe the problem isn't in the JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you! I am using http://sunspot.github.com/ for search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix in this question:

[Replicating Bootstraps main nav and subnav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179708/replicating-bootstraps-main-nav-and-subnav)

This is the code:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    // If has not activated (has no attribute "data-top"
    if (!$('.subnav').attr('data-top')) {
        // If already fixed, then do nothing
        if ($('.subnav').hasClass('subnav-fixed')) return;
        // Remember top position
        var offset = $('.subnav').offset()
        $('.subnav').attr('data-top', offset.top);
    }

    if ($('.subnav').attr('data-top') - $('.subnav').outerHeight() <= $(this).scrollTop())
        $('.subnav').addClass('subnav-fixed');
    else
        $('.subnav').removeClass('subnav-fixed');
});
```

Thank you