# How to fix element at top in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have problem with position on CSS.

I create 3 elements: a menu `navbar`, a category bar (to filter content), and content.

It looks like this:

```
*Menu `navbar`*
Home             About US

*Category bar*
Category 1       Category 2

*Content*
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
```

When scrolling down, the menu show is hidden, and category bar will be fixed on top.

Screenshot:

[image]

When I add CSS code to fix category bar at top:

```
ul#filters {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

ul#filters li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

It looks like:

[image]

I expected output is:

When loading page success, like the first image in my answer. When the user scrolls down, menu hidden, category bar fix top, content at below category bar.

Like this:

[image]

Note: change menu bar to category bar

Here is my code:

```css
ul#filters {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

ul#filters li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed green child-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse  ">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about-us" class="scroll">About US</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <ul id="filters" class="loaiduan clearfix">
        <li class="li-selected">
            <a href="">Category 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="li-selected">
            <a href="">Category 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="container" class="list">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit temporibus cumque impedit repellendus vero, modi voluptatem id dignissimos assumenda quis fuga suscipit provident ab fugiat dolores at numquam dolorem adipisci?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit temporibus cumque impedit repellendus vero, modi voluptatem id dignissimos assumenda quis fuga suscipit provident ab fugiat dolores at numquam dolorem adipisci?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit temporibus cumque impedit repellendus vero, modi voluptatem id dignissimos assumenda quis fuga suscipit provident ab fugiat dolores at numquam dolorem adipisci?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit temporibus cumque impedit repellendus vero, modi voluptatem id dignissimos assumenda quis fuga suscipit provident ab fugiat dolores at numquam dolorem adipisci?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit temporibus cumque impedit repellendus vero, modi voluptatem id dignissimos assumenda quis fuga suscipit provident ab fugiat dolores at numquam dolorem adipisci?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit temporibus cumque impedit repellendus vero, modi voluptatem id dignissimos assumenda quis fuga suscipit provident ab fugiat dolores at numquam dolorem adipisci?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @mplungjan. I expected output is: When loading page success, like the first image in my answer. When the user scrolls down, menu hidden, category bar fix top, content at below category bar. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/BgiXiei.png. Note: change menu bar to category bar.

Comment: Update your question instead of posing comments please

Comment: yes. I was updated.

Comment: @vanloc There's some confusion in your question as far as I interpret it. You mention that the menu bar is the one with the white background at the top of the screen and the category bar is the one with the different white boxes. But then later you seem to contradict that by saying you want the category bar to stick to the top as shown in a screenshot you provide, but the screenshot shows the very top menu with the white background fixed to the top of the screen. Which one should stick and which one should scroll with the rest of the page?

Comment: @vanloc Also, in general, getting the menu to stick to the top of the screen only after the user scrolls is not possible with only CSS. You need JavaScript for that. If that's an acceptable solution, update your question to add a JavaScript tag (and jQuery, if you happen to be using that already). Technically there is a CSS solution with `position: sticky`, but [browser support is still pretty bad](http://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Bootstrap's navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar).

You can make stick it on top with just [one parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275381/make-scrolling-navbar-stick-at-top-of-browser-in-bootstrap), plus it's responsive.

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use bootstrap class (`navbar-fixed-top`)

### Example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top green child-nav">
```

Hope to help!